# TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function despite setting data: [ ]

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to store the data in ItemLists component for which I need to first map over. But getting `TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: []
  }
}

componentDidMount() {    
  fetch('items.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response");
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({data: data});
  });
}


render() {     
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.state.data.map(function(object){
        return (
          <ItemLists key={object.id} data={object}/>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

if I change the code to:

```
render() {     
  return (
    <div className="App">
      return (
        <ItemLists data={this.state.data}/>
      )
    </div>
   )
 }
```

error I get is: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {artist, title, level, released, rating}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead` pointing towards `this.setState({data: data});`

json data:

```
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "cnt",
        "level": "12"
      },
      {
        "name": "stewart",
        "level": "6"
      },
      {
        "name": "nic",
        "level": "7"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: If you write `console.log(Array.isArray(data));` in the fetch callback, does it log `true`?

Comment: `.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({data: data});
  });  ` logs the data. AND `console.log(Array.isArray(data));` logs False

Comment: Alright. Are you sure the JSON looks like you have pasted it in your second code snippet? Maybe it's an object `{ ... }` instead of an array `[ ... ]`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `fetch` request is completed you set the `data` array in your state to the parsed JSON object. Since regular objects don't have a `map` method like arrays have, you get the error.

You could set the `data` in state to be the `data` array in the parsed JSON object instead.

```js
componentDidMount() {    
  fetch('items.json')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response");
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ data: response.data });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Arrow function` when you use the function in `React Component`

```js
let JSONDATA = 
  {
    data: [
      {
        name: "cnt",
        level: "12"
      },
      {
        name: "stewart",
        level: "6"
      },
      {
        name: "nic",
        level: "7"
      }
    ]
  }

let { data } = JSONDATA;

data.map((obj)=>{
  console.log(obj)
})
```